# How do I open screen with many tabs to execute some commands within each one

Tags: 12.04, bash, gnome-terminal, gnu-screen

How to open screen with many tabs?

How can I execute some commands within each tab, plus giving the main screen window a name to call it again later to execute other commands?

For example, I have a loop this is the code inside it:

```
gnomeTab+=( --tab -e "cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage ")
```

and I run the result after finishing the loop in gnome terminal like this:

```
gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
```

I want to do exactly as happens in the gnome terminal to open many tabs within the main terminal window and execute this command. But, I want to re-do this by GNUScreen.

**in addition,  I want to give the main screen window a name: For example: let it be "screen1"**

Comment: Do you want to display the cpulimit in all screen tabs?

Comment: i want in each tab to execute a cpulimit command to limit something or execute what ever i want in each tab and i want to give a name or title to the screen window the main one ,so i can call it later with its name and open more tabs within it

Comment: See my answer over on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one). Also, you probably weren't aware but you're not suppose to cross post on the Stack Exchange websites, which askubuntu is a part of.

Comment: no i didnt know that , i wont repeat it thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[slm](https://askubuntu.com/users/17531/slm%20slm) already answered it over here thanks to him

[How to open tabs windows in Gnu-screen & execute commands within each one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one?noredirect=1#comment108967_74785)